# Requets return only 403 (forbidden) even if csrf is disabled. Spring Security Jwt

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, jwt, http-status-code-403

These are the classes I created for authentication using jwt.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/authentication", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(
            @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest
    ) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()
                    )
            );
        } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
            throw new Exception("incorrect username or password", ex);
        }
        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
                .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        final String jwt = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));
    }
}





public class AuthenticationRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public AuthenticationRequest() {
    }

    public AuthenticationRequest(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}



public class AuthenticationResponse {
    private final String jwt;

    public AuthenticationResponse(String jwt) {
        this.jwt = jwt;
    }

    public String getJwt() {
        return jwt;
    }
}



import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader
                = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;
        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
        }
        if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}



import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.Function;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Service
public class JwtUtil {
    private String SECRET_KEY = "secret";
    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }
    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }
    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }
    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token){
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }
    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }
    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SECRET_KEY).compact();
    }
    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())
            && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}



import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new User("foo", "foo", new ArrayList<>());
    }
}



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authentication")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }



    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

All requests are returning a 403 error even though I provide the jwt in the header. What I am doing wrong? Only request worked is /authentication post request that returns a jwt. other than that nothing works.
I am new to spring and spring security, if the answer is obvious I am sorry
thanks

Comment: is it working in local when you bring it up and send the request through postman?

Comment: No. I only run in in my local already

Comment: just follow the steps in the article and let me know https://medium.com/@dassum/securing-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-and-jdbc-token-store-67558a7d6c29

Answer (score 0):

There're two main reasons for this issue:

1. Credentials that you send are not valid (probably token expired)
2. When there're not .exceptionHandling() configured then Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint is used by default

I'd suggest to add a custom endpoint in the security configuration:

```
.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
```

where jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint extends AuthenticationEntryPoint and you can define the return codes depending on the AuthenticationException